# How to fix compatibility issues between GLSL version 1.5 and version 3.0 ES

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, compatibility

I've recently come back to working on an old passion project of mine (I last worked on this 2 years ago for the last time) which uses GLSL shaders. The project uses a whole bunch of shader files like this:

```
#version 150

in vec3 color;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void){

    out_Color = vec4(color,1.0);

}
```

I get the following error when running the program using this file:

```
error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES
```

I'm assuming that in the last 2 years I have updated some of the drivers of my PC and GLSL version 1.5 is no longer supported on my PC. I've tried using any of the other versions by using the following headers, each giving different errors reported here in order of supported versions given above:

**#version 110:**

```
0:3(1): error: `in' qualifier in declaration of `color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10
0:5(1): error: `out' qualifier in declaration of `out_Color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10
```

**#version 120:**

```
0:3(1): error: `in' qualifier in declaration of `color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.20
0:5(1): error: `out' qualifier in declaration of `out_Color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.20
```

**#version 130:**

```
0:1(1): error: `in' qualifier in declaration of `position' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10
0:2(1): error: `in' qualifier in declaration of `textureCoordinates' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10
0:4(1): error: `out' qualifier in declaration of `passTextureCoordinates' only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10
```

**#version 100:**

```
0:3(1): error: `in' qualifier in declaration of `color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL ES 1.00
0:3(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type `vec3'
0:5(1): error: `out' qualifier in declaration of `out_Color' only valid for function parameters in GLSL ES 1.00
0:5(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type `vec4'
```

**#version 300 es:**

```
0:3(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type `vec3'
0:5(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type `vec4'
```

So now, assuming just reverting to version 1.5 is not possible anymore or not the right solution here, I need to convert my shader files to one of the versions above and fix the errors. So here is my question: Is this the right approach? Do I really need to change GLSL version and, in that case, which version would be the best to use? Do I need to also change the java code or will changing the version of GLSL not have any effect on my java LWJGL code?

I'm sorry if this is a bit of a beginner question and I'm completely wrong here, as I mentioned I just got back into this project.

Here is some info about my current installation:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I'm working on debian:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:    9.13
Codename:   stretch
```

I added the following code to find out the versions of LWJGL & OpenGL used for the project:

```
System.out.println("[DEBUG]: OS name " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
System.out.println("[DEBUG]: OS version " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
System.out.println("[DEBUG]: LWJGL version " + org.lwjgl.Sys.getVersion());
System.out.println("[DEBUG]: OpenGL version " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

The output of that was:

```
[DEBUG]: OS name Linux
[DEBUG]: OS version 4.9.0-4-amd64
[DEBUG]: LWJGL version 3.0.0a
[DEBUG]: OpenGL version 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
```

Comment: Which OpenGL context did you create? Which version, which profile? Did you try to use a Core Profile? I'm almost 100% sure that no graphicscard supports 3.0 ES but not 150.

Comment: @BDL I'm not sure what that means entirely but I added all information I could find! hopefully this is enough

Comment: You are right, 150 (OpenGL 3.2) is not supported. But 330 (OpenGL 3.3) is supported in a core profile. Judging from the shader code given, it should be fully compatible with OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: if I use `#version 330` I get the following error: `0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES`. Can that be  because the project is old and therefore so are the external libraries?

Comment: I've added the version of LWJGL in an eddit in the question. I'm assuming I need to update my version of LWJGL to make use of OpenGL 3.3, right? If so, from what I've heard, There are a lot of methods that have been replaced & functionality that has changed that then needs to be fixed in my java code...

Comment: No. You just have to request a core profile when creating the window/opengl context. How do you create your window? Do you request a specific OpenGL version?

Comment: I believe it comes down to calling these functions: `glfwCreateWindow()`, `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);`, `glfwShowWindow(window);` For the first function I've left away the parameters here so it's easier to read but it's just stuff like height, width & title. There is nothing in the process that I can see that has to do with a core profile. I'm sorry if this is not the right information. I'm just out of the loop after not having seen this code for 2 years... If you want you can see the code here too: https://github.com/BRHSM/LWJGL_Engine it's very unorganized which I also want to fix...

Comment: Your window hints don't work. They have to be called **before** calling `glCreateWindow`. Also note that a debug context is only possible in OpenGL 4.3+. I suggest you request major version 3, minor version 3, and `GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! thank you so much! You should write it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GPU supports either up to OpenGL 3.0 in a Compatibility profile, or OpenGL 3.3 in a Core Profile. The requested version 150 (OpenGL 3.2) is not supported.

Your shader seems to be compatible with OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile, so I recommend to use the following settings:

```
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Note, that these window hints have to be set **before** calling `glCreateWindow`.

Comment: And don't forget to bind a VAO in Core, can't draw otherwise.